# Eclipse PDE Build plugins output some folders are jar-ed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am running eclipse PDE Build from ant file. I succesfuly get the product but in the ant generated product I get some folders in plugins directory jar-ed unlike the folders I get during the export product from eclipse.

What can be the reason to have the plugins as jar but not folder ? Is there a parameter to set?

Comment: Compressing plugins into jars is the default, the normal product export should also be doing this. Are you using a features based build or a plugins based build?

Comment: We don't have features, we are using a plugins based build. And the folders that are jarred are 3rd party plugins that are to be delivered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the MANIFEST.MF file of each plugin, you can specify this property:

Eclipse-BundleShape: dir

By default the plugin is jar-ed. With this option, it is expanded as a directory during installation of the plugin.

Note: This option is available since Eclipse 3.5 only.

Comment: Plugin does not belong to us, it is not in our workspace. We just deliver it as a third party. Is there another way to achieve this ?

Comment: These jarred plugins are not in our workspace. They are third party plugins that we deliver in our product. We have them not jarred when we export from eclipse product. But when we export them via PDE Build ant script they are jarred. They are at target definition and we want them to be not compiled to be jarred.

Comment: If this is third party plugin then you cannot modify its 'bundle shape' (dir or jar ), unless you patch it. But nothing tells you this plugin will still work, since it may rely on the fact it is a dir or a jar for loading its resources.

Comment: Be careful anyway. I have noticed that sometimes the build create a jar, but it is expanded when deployed. Indeed there may be a difference between the export from eclipse ant the command line pde packaging, but in the end, when deployed, and after first run (of eclipse and thus P2), the jar is expanded as a directory.